# Unable to read GPS coordinate of camera roll images

Tags: ios, gps, metadata, exif, ios-camera

In one of app I'm developing,I am retrieving EXIF data from images.I want to get GPS coordinate of images on iOS device.As I get GPS coordinate of an image taken by UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera.But when I try to select images from gallery which are taken by camera roll it doesn't gives me GPS coordinate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Images taken with UIImagePickerController do not contain location data (unlike those taken with the Camera app).

Camera app developers have to capture the location data separately at the time of capture, add it to the metadata that *is* there, and then save the image with the revised metadata.